# MapView in mapbox-navigation-android returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, mapbox

I'm working with mapbox-navigation-android and facing an issue where my MapView reference is always null. I've initialized MapboxNavigationApp as per the documentation but can't seem to access the MapView from my NavigationView.

Here's my Kotlin code:

```
val navigationOptions = NavigationOptions.Builder(this.context)
    .accessToken(this.token)
    .build()

MapboxNavigationApp
    .setup(navigationOptions)
    .attach(this.activity as LifecycleOwner)

var map = binding.navigationView.findViewById<MapView>(R.id.mapView)
```

And my corresponding XML layout:

```
<com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:accessToken="this-can-be-skip-since-we-set-it-later"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
</com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.NavigationView>
```

The map variable remains null after this code runs. I've made sure that the access token is valid and that the context is correctly passed. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step or if there's an issue with the library.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest what might be going wrong?